# Is it fine to use JSON.stringify for deep comparisons and cloning?

Tags: javascript, json, equality, deep-copy, object-comparison

After attempting several implementations for deep comparison and copying for JSON-serializable objects, I've noticed the fastest often are just:

```
function deep_clone(a){
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
};
function is_equal(a,b){
    return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
};
```

I feel like this is cheating, though. Like I'll find some problem that will annoy me on future. Is it fine to use those?

Comment: I only use JSON serializable objects.

Comment: FWIW article being strict about saying 'JSON object' and stating that there is no such thing as 'JSON object' http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum not exactly duplicate, but that guys is using the old JSON lib anyway.

Comment: @DanC so what do I call a JSON-serializable object?

Comment: JSON is now natively implemented in many browsers, which completely changes any performance analysis.

Comment: Fair enough, in that case there is no problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

JavaScript does not guarantee the order of keys.

If they are entered in the same order, this approach would work most of the time, but it would not be reliable.

Also, it would return false for objects that were deeply equal, but whose keys were entered in a different order:

```
JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2}) === "{"a":1,"b":2}"

JSON.stringify({ b: 2, a: 1}) === "{"b":2,"a":1}"
```

Comment: True. That makes the other answer wrong. Reviewed the tick.

Comment: Javascript *does* guarantee key order, in recent versions. See e.g http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html for an overview. In practice, JS engines were already doing this.

I would argue that since the key order is now defined, two objects with the same keys in different order should not be considered equivalent. Thus the `JSON.stringify` comparison works.

Comment: Has anyone tried to make use of sorting yet? Something along the lines of 
`JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2 }).split("").sort().join("") === JSON.stringify({ b: 2, a: 1 }).split("").sort().join("")`

Comment: @wmik sorting will not work. consider this example

`JSON.stringify({ a: 12, b: 12 }).split("").sort().join("") === JSON.stringify({ b: 11, a: 22 }).split("").sort().join("")`

expected false but got true.

Answer (score 16):

I realize it's an old question, but I just wanted to add a bit more to the answers, since someone might otherwise walk away from this page mistakenly thinking that using `JSON.stringify` for comparisons/cloning will work without issue so long as it isn't used to compare/clone objects whose members are unordered. (To be fair to the accepted answer, they *shouldn't* walk away thinking that; it says, "If [the members] are entered in the same order, this approach would work *most of the time*.")

Code probably illustrates the potential hiccups best:

```
JSON.stringify(NaN) === JSON.stringify(null)
// => true

JSON.stringify(Infinity) === JSON.stringify(null)
// => true

// or, to put it all together:
JSON.stringify({ val1: (1 / 0), val2: parseInt("hi there"), val3: NaN }) === JSON.stringify({ val1: NaN, val2: null, val3: null })
// => true

// and here's the same example with "cloning" rather than comparison:
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ val1: (1 / 0), val2: parseInt("hi there"), val3: NaN }))
// => Object {val1: null, val2: null, val3: null}
```

These are quirks that can cause trouble even when ordering isn't an issue (which, as others have said, it can be). It's probably not likely in most cases that these quirks will rear their ugly heads, but it's good to be aware of them, since they could result in some really hard to find bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the addition!

Comment: The question asks about "deep comparison and copying for JSON-serializable objects", so `Infinity`, `NaN` and other values that aren't part of JSON aren't really any more relevant than objects that contain functions, `window` objects, `undefined`, regexes, etc...

Comment: As someone who got here looking for answers for the more general "not necessarily JSON-serializable objects", seeing as this is not mentioned in the title, I really appreciate the additions provided in this answer.
I think people often forget that answers here on SO also serve as reference for other people facing *similiar* issues, not to mention having such negative attitude towards people giving additional information is actually detrimental to the community.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the key-value pairs are always in the same order, yes, you can use stringify to compare using the deep equals operator (===).

Comment: it's strict equality, not deep equality operator and you can use regular equality (`==`) aswell to compare two strings from `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function to deep compare any object array or value:
Use it if you want :) I tested it with very huge sample of objects with randomized entry order in objects and arrays too.

```
function c(x, y) {
  if (!x && !y) return !0
  if (!x || !y) return !1
  if (typeof (x) !==
      typeof (y)) return !1
  if (x instanceof Array) {
    if (
      x.length != y.length) return !1
    const f = []
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (!c(x[i], y[i])) f.push(i)
    }
    const g = [...f]
    for (const i of f) {
      let r = !1
      for (const j of g) {
        if (
          c(x[i], y[j])) {
          g.splice(g.indexOf(j), 1)
          r++
          break
        }
      }
      if (!r) { return !1 }
    }
    return !0
  } else if (x instanceof Object) {
    const e1 =
          Object.entries(x)
    try {
      return c(e1, r(Object.entries(y),
        e1))
    } catch (e) {
      return !1
    }
  } else {
    return x === y
  }

  function r(
    u, v) {
    const a = []
    if (u.length != v.length) return u
    for (
      let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
      a.push(m(u, v[i][0]))
    }
    return a
  }

  function m(a, k) {
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i][0] === k) return [a[i][0], a[i][1]]
    }
    throw 0
  }
}
```