# Filter out objects from another array in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an `allItems` array of objects

```
allItems = [
    { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'item2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'item3' }
]
```

I want it to filter out and not contain the objects contained in another array from my component.

```
fewItems = [
    { id: 2, name: 'item2' }
]
```

so, `filteredItems` should be :

```
filteredItems = [
    { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
    { id: 3, name: 'item3' }
]
```

And when another object from `allItems` is added to `fewItems`, it needs to disappear from the `filteredItems` one.

I would like to do this in pure vanilla JS, with no specific library.

Thanks ahead !

Comment: what is the output u want

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Do you want to be able to do this with just JavaScript or with a library?

Comment: @Chris you're right I should have specified this in the question. Edited again.

Comment: @JeremyBelolo I think you made a much better question with those simple changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filteredItems =  this.allItems.filter(x => {
    return !this.fewItems.some(y => JSON.stringify(y) == JSON.stringify(x))
});
```

Comment: just be carefull with stringify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376185/is-it-fine-to-use-json-stringify-for-deep-comparisons-and-cloning.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var allItems = [
    { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'item2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'item3' }
];

var fewItems = [
    { id: 2, name: 'item2' }
];

var result3 = _(allItems) 
        .differenceBy(fewItems, 'id', 'name')
        .map(_.partial(_.pick, _, 'id', 'name'))
        .value();

console.log(result3);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

**EDIT**

Without Lodash

```js
var allItems = [
    { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'item2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'item3' }
];

var fewItems = [
    { id: 2, name: 'item2' }
];


var props = ['id', 'name'];
var result = allItems.filter(function(o1){
     return !fewItems.some(function(o2){
        return o1.id === o2.id;        
    });
}).map(function(o){
     return props.reduce(function(newo, name){
        newo[name] = o[name];
        return newo;
    }, {});
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this... But I don't like the idea of integrating lodash in an Angular app. I would really like to do it without, if at all possible.

Comment: @JeremyBelolo check the solution without lodash, edited answer

Comment: So you say it's an Angular app? so probably best to use Angular's Comparison methods for equality, since you don't wnat to use Lodash: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals I thought you put in original quesiton Angular but now it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var allItems = [
     { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'item2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'item3' }
    ];
    
    var fewItems = [
        { id: 2, name: 'item2' }
    ];
    
    var keys = Object.keys( fewItems[0] ) 
    
    var result = allItems.filter( 
      function(item){ 
        for( var k = fewItems.length-1; k>=0; --k){ 
          var dontWant = fewItems[k]; 
          var i=keys.length-1; 
          for( ; i>=0; --i ){ 
            if( dontWant[keys[i]] != item[keys[i]]){  break; } 
          } 
          if( i == -1){ return false;} 
        } 
        return true; 
      }
    );

    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS solution

```js
var allItems = [
  { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'item2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'item3' }
];

var fewItems = [
  { id: 2, name: 'item2' }
];

var result3 = allItems
  .filter(item => {
    for(let restrictedItem of fewItems) {
      if (JSON.stringify(restrictedItem) === JSON.stringify(item)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  })

console.log(result3);
```