# How to find occurence of objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to know if an array of objects contains at least two same objects in it, in JavaScript.

I have a form that allow people to create questions (title, description, type, answer options). I need to check whether the user has entered multiple answer options with the same label. They are stored in an array.

```
// The array of answer options
let array = [{value: 'a'}, {value: 'b'}, {value: 'c'}, {value: 'a'}]
```

I tried using `array.indexOf({value: 'a'})` and `array.lastIndexOf({value: 'a'})` but they both give me an index of -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate objects are never `===` to each other, so you'll have to use a different method. One option is to create a Set of the stringified objects, and return true once any duplicate string is found:

```js
const hasDupes = (arr) => {
  const strings = new Set();
  for (const obj of arr) {
    const string = JSON.stringify(obj);
    if (strings.has(string)) {
      return true;
    }
    strings.add(string);
  }
  return false;
};
console.log(hasDupes([{value: 'a'}, {value: 'b'}, {value: 'c'}, {value: 'a'}]));
console.log(hasDupes([{value: 'a'}, {value: 'b'}, {value: 'c'}]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned about the `value` property and you use case is not more complex and you can simply do this in one line via:

```js
let hasDupes = arr => new Set(arr.map(x => x.value)).size !== arr.length

console.log(hasDupes([{value: 'a'}, {value: 'b'}, {value: 'c'},{value: 'a'}]))
console.log(hasDupes([{value: 'a'}, {value: 'b'}, {value: 'c'}]))
```

You would use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to add the values of `value` and if the size of it is smaller than the actual input array length than you had duplicates. There is no need to do `JSON.stringify`, compare strings etc if you only care about that one property being checked.

Also [JSON.stringify has issues when comparing equality of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376185/is-it-fine-to-use-json-stringify-for-deep-comparisons-and-cloning).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
let array = [{value: 'a'}, {value: 'b'}, {value: 'c'}, {value: 'a'}];
const index = array.findIndex(({ value }) => value == "a");
console.log(index);
```

Comment: This gives me the index of the first occurence right? I would like to know if there are multiple `{value: 'a'}`, not just the index of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

indexOf will return the instance of an object

```
{value: 'a'} !== {value: 'a'};
```

as they are both different instances of objects.

You can find the object

```
const obj = array.find(item => item.value === 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash.js to compare two objects.
Please see the sample below.

```
let array = [{ value: "a" }, { value: "b" }, { value: "c" }, { value: "a" }];

const object = { value: "a" };

countObjOccurrences = object => {
  let occurances = 0;
  array.map(item => {
    if (_.isEqual(item, object)) {
      occurances += 1;
    }
  });
  return occurances;
};
```

This function will return 2.