# How to remove all next elements from array in javascript or lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of object `[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{a:4},{a:5}]`.

I want to find index of `{a:3}` and remove all next elements from index of `{a:3}`.

Result should look like `[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}]` and removed elements will be `{a:4},{a:5}`.

Comment: do you want a new array or keeping the old without unwanted? please add the wanted result and the code, you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#findIndex()` to find that object by its number, or `Array#indexOf()` if you have a reference to it.

Then, you can either set the array's length (mutating) or use `Array#slice()` (not mutating), to reduce its length:

```js
const array = [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{a:4},{a:5}]

const i = array.findIndex(({a}) => a === 3)

const arrayCopy = array.slice(0, i + 1)
//or:
array.length = i + 1

console.log(i)
console.log(arrayCopy)
console.log(array)
```

Or with `Array#indexOf()`:

```js
//If you have a reference from somewhere:
const ref = {a:3}

const array = [{a:1},{a:2},ref,{a:4},{a:5}]

const i = array.indexOf(ref)

const arrayCopy = array.slice(0, i + 1)
//or:
array.length = i + 1

console.log(i)
console.log(arrayCopy)
console.log(array)
```

Alternatively, if you don't have a reference, but **it's *guaranteed* that the array is sorted**, you can use a binary search, that makes this much faster for large arrays:

```js
function binarySearch(array, target, cb) {
  let start = 0, end = array.length
  while(start < end){
    const middle = ((end - start - 1) >>> 1)  + start
    const middleVal = cb(array[middle], middle)
    if(middleVal === target) return middle
    if(middleVal < target)
      start = middle + 1
    else
      end = middle
  }
  return -1
};

const array = [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{a:4},{a:5}]

const i = binarySearch(array, 3, ({a}) => a)

const arrayCopy = array.slice(0, i + 1)
//or:
array.length = i + 1

console.log(i)
console.log(arrayCopy)
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 3):

One line vanilla JS with `slice` and `findIndex`

```js
const data = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 4 }, { a: 5 }];

const res = data.slice(
  0,
  data.findIndex((el) => JSON.stringify(el) === JSON.stringify({ a: 3 })) + 1
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I don't want to compare it with array element value like `a===3` . I really need to be done with indexes of an array

Comment: @ShopifyGuy hmm, so you might need deep object comparision, I updated the answer with a JSON.stringify solution

Comment: The `JSON.stringify` method is inefficient and might not work in some cases, etc. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36012146/8376184)